# what happens to a process when its parent sshd process terminates?

Tags: linux, ssh, posix, process, openssh

If I am running a shell on `host1` and I do `ssh host2 some-command`, then I close the terminal window (or otherwise kill the `ssh` process on `host1`) it seems that the `sshd` process on `host2` terminates pretty promptly.  But... what happens to `some-command`?  Depending on what command it is, it sometimes terminates, but it sometimes doesn't.  What signals does `some-command` receive?  What file descriptors (if any) are manipulated and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not receive any signals.  If they were not redirected in some way, the three standard IO streams were pipes to/from the ssh process, so a read from stdin will return EOF and a write to either stdout or stderr will fail and raise a SIGPIPE.  If some-command does not do I/O on the standard streams, it will have no reason to terminate prematurely.

Comment: are you sure?  `ssh` may create a terminal aka pseudo-tty (depending on the options) and if it does, I'd expect other processes for which that tty is the controlling terminal to receive `SIGHUP`.

Comment: Aha, but that is the key.  `ssh somehost some-command` does *not* allocate a pty!  It simply makes a pipe.  You have to ask for a pty with `-t`.  So the behavior I was seeing which lead me to ask this question (my jobs not receiving any signal, just having their stdin closed) makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `dtrace` on your machine, you can check it with

```
dtrace -n 'proc:::signal-send /pid/ { printf("%s -%d %d",execname,args[2],args[1]->pr_pid); }'
```

command from [here](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTrace_Topics_One_Liners). Also see [this](http://www.seedsofgenius.net/solaris/dtrace-1-liners-and-scripts).

I do not have dtrace on my Linux machine now. But I can check it later.